# How can I decompress h264 stream from web-camera on GPU (CUDA) with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, webcam, h.264, opencv3.0

I can use [`VideoCapture cap(0);`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#VideoCapture) to read h264 stream from web-camera and decompress it on CPU. But I use 10 web-cameras, so it burn my CPU very much.

[`gpu::VideoReader_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/video.html?highlight=h264#gpu-videoreader-gpu) supports to decompress h264 video stream from file, but not from web-camera: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/video.html?highlight=h264#gpu-videoreader-gpu-open

```
C++: void gpu::VideoReader_GPU::open(const std::string& filename)
C++: void gpu::VideoReader_GPU::open(const cv::Ptr<VideoSource>& source)
```

How can I decompress h264 video stream from web-camera on GPU (CUDA) with OpenCV?

Comment: did you get any solution so far??

Comment: @tod No. Also `gpu::VideoReader_GPU` does not work even with files on OpenCV+CUDA 6.5-7.5 - bug with high-priority: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4858  I.e. impossible to compile OpenCV with library nvcuvid.